# Wrong exception in nestjs e2e testing

Tags: nestjs

In test I receive InternalServerErrorException() instead of ConflictException though it is working fine when I test in postman. I want to test if it throws ConflictException when username already exists

This is my test in jest

```
it('(POST) - throws conflict exception if username already exists', async () => {
    const mockCredentialsDto = { username: 'user1234', password: 'password' };

    // First request to create the user
    await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/auth/signup')
      .send(mockCredentialsDto)
      .expect(201);

    // Second request with the same credentials
    const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/auth/signup')
      .send(mockCredentialsDto)
      .expect(409);
    expect(response.body.message).toEqual('Username already exists');
  });
```

```
Expected: "Username already exists"
Received: "Internal Server Error"

  59 |       .send(mockCredentialsDto)
  60 |       .expect(500);
> 61 |     expect(response.body.message).toEqual('Username already exists');
     |                                   ^
  62 |   });
```

This is my code

```
  @Post('/signup')
  async createUser(
    @Body() authCredentialsDto: AuthCredentialsDto,
  ): Promise<{ accessToken: string }> {
    try {
      return await this.authService.signUp(authCredentialsDto);
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === '23505') {
        throw new ConflictException('Username already exists');
      } else {
        throw new InternalServerErrorException();
      }
    }
  }
```

This is whole test file

```
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import * as path from 'path';
import { AppModule } from '../src/app.module';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';

describe('AuthController', () => {
  let moduleFixture: TestingModule;
  let app: INestApplication;

  beforeAll(async () => {
    moduleFixture = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [
        TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
          useFactory: () => ({
            type: 'sqlite',
            database: ':memory:',
            entities: [path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}')],
            synchronize: true,
            logging: false,
          }),
        }),
        AppModule,
      ],
    }).compile();
    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    await moduleFixture.close();
  });

  it('(POST) - register a new user', async () => {
    const mockCredentialsDto = { username: 'user123', password: 'password' };

    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/auth/signup')
      .send(mockCredentialsDto)
      .expect(201)
      .then((res) => {
        expect(res.body.accessToken).toBeDefined();
      });
  });

  it('(POST) - throws conflict exception if username already exists', async () => {
    const mockCredentialsDto = { username: 'user1234', password: 'password' };

    // First request to create the user
    await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/auth/signup')
      .send(mockCredentialsDto)
      .expect(201);

    // Second request with the same credentials
    const response = await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/auth/signup')
      .send(mockCredentialsDto)
      .expect(409);
    expect(response.body.message).toEqual('Username already exists');
  });

  it('(POST) - login the new user', async () => {
    const mockCredentialsDto = { username: 'user123', password: 'password' };

    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/auth/signin')
      .send(mockCredentialsDto)
      .expect(201)
      .then((res) => {
        expect(res.body.accessToken).toBeDefined();
      });
  });

  it('(POST) - throws error if user doesnt exist', async () => {
    const mockCredentialsDto = { username: 'user124', password: 'password' };

    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/auth/signin')
      .send(mockCredentialsDto)
      .expect(500);
  });
});
```

It looks like my error.code is undefined in testing

Comment: Does sqlite throw and error with a `.code` property equal to `23505`?